# C - Does printf() cause thread to sleep?

Tags: c, printf

When a program is doing I/O, my understanding is that the thread will briefly sleep and then resume (e.g. when writing to a file). My question is that when we do printing using `printf()`, does a C program thread sleep in any way ?

Comment: Yes, this can happen. For example, in a standard linux environment, the underlying `write()`-syscall can block

Comment: In C, there is no thread. And yes: I/O can block.

Comment: @wildplasser: In C11, there are threads.

Comment: while you can't assume as mandatory rule that a thread performing I/O sleeps (this really depends on the underlying OS), in almost all real systems this quietly happen. The reason is that directly or indirectly the concurrence for a shared resource, disk or screen, requires interlocked access at some stage of execution.

Comment: It also depends on where your `stdout` is redirected. If it pointing to a file, it might block for disk write. If it redirected to `/dev/null`, the thread probably won't sleep. Just enter the kernel and exit when the actual `write` happens like @Ctx said.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I thought there's an optional `threads.h` starting C11. No?

Comment: @UnmannedPlayer: yes — that's what I said (tersely).  See [C11 §7.26 Threads `<threads.h>`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.26) primarily, though there are other references too, notably [§6.10.3 Conditional feature macros](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.8.3) and [§6.7.1 Storage class specifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.1), etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My bad. Sorry. I misread it as (no-threads).

Answer (score 1):

Since you've specifically asked for [`printf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html), I'm going to assume that you mean in the most generic way where it will fill a reasonably sized buffer and invoke the system call [`write(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) to `stdout` and that the `stdout` happens to point to your terminal.

In most operating systems, when you invoke certain system calls the calling thread/process is removed from CPU runnable list and placed in a separate waiting list. This is true for all I/O calls like read/write/etc. Being temporarily removed from processing due to I/O is not the same as being put to sleep via a timer.

For example, in Linux there's uninterruptible sleep state of a thread/process specifically meant for I/O waiting, while interruptible sleep state for those thread/process that are waiting on timers and events. Though, from a dumb user's perspective they both seem to be same, their implementation behind the scenes are significantly different.

To answer your question, a call to [`printf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) isn't exactly sleeping but waiting for the buffer to be flushed to device rather than actually being in sleep. Even then there are a few more quirks which you can read about it in [`signal(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and even  more about various process/thread states from [Marek's](https://idea.popcount.org/2012-12-11-linux-process-states/) blog.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Much of the point of `stdio.h` is that it **buffers** I/O: a call to `printf` will often simply put text into a memory buffer (owned by the library by default) and perform *zero* system calls, thus offering no opportunity to yield the CPU.  Even when something like `write(2)` *is* called, the thread may continue running: the kernel can copy the data into kernel memory (from which it will be transferred to the disk later, *e.g.* by DMA) and return immediately.

Of course, even on a single-core system, most operating systems frequently interrupt the running thread in order to share it.  So another thread can still run at any time, even if no blocking calls are made.

Comment: According to common terminology, you do not call a process "sleeping" when it just isn't scheduled at the moment, but is otherwise ready to run

Comment: @Ctx: I said exactly that: I wrote “put it to sleep” just to mean that the thread could stop running momentarily, as it was phrased in the question.

Comment: No, this was not phrased in the question. The OP talked about "writing to a file", which can indeed result in "sleeping" (for example, status D in linux).

Comment: @Ctx: I read “sleep in any way” as “become unscheduled”.  I/O wait isn’t actually _sleep_ either: that’s only for timed waits (including `select` and friends).

Comment: I disagree, I/O wait is technically and actually (uninterruptible) sleep. And I do not read "sleep in any way" as "become unscheduled", and judging from the context of the question, neither does the OP.

Comment: @DavisHerring getting unscheduled shouldn't be counted as a "sleep" because any program may do that. Even something simple like `int main(void){return 0;}`. A sleep would be mean the process is __not__ ready to be scheduled again till some specific event has completed.

Comment: @Ctx: The literature seems divided on the subject: some distinguish sleeping and waiting as I did, which can be useful (but is less so for the variation).  Fortunately it’s immaterial here.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: I never called that _sleep_, but I tried to handle the possibility that the questioner had done so.  I edited the confusing mention out; hopefully no one needed it anyway.

Comment: @DavisHerring fair enough. Not my DV anyway.